# How Spring Data Mongodb convert date from $date to ISODate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data Mongodb auto parser date object to '$date': millisecond, this query consume more than 1 min to return data, I find ISODate query is more quickly than $date, How I make Spring Data Mongodb parser date object to ISODate.

Answer (score 0):

It is base on your DataType, As i use Instant, mongodb auto convert it to ISODate.

But as you said the date type as millisecond, that cost many time to return data, you should check your query first....

Please show the Object and query for more support

Comment: you can find more in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292497/mongorepository-query-failed-to-parse-string-as-a-date/55294518#55294518